How do I delay the stay/exit from a state in the animator statemachine in the StateMachineBehaviour(direct file inside the animation) in Unity
I am making a boss and i followed brackeys boss tutorial, there he added a statemachine behaviour to the animation, but he only has one attack type per the stateof the boss, I wanted to have 2 different attacks on my boss so I made a switch, all parameters as shown in the video, ofc added bool parameter AttackSwitch:

bool switchAttack = false;

// OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        rb = animator.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boss = animator.GetComponent<Boss>();
    }

    // OnStateUpdate is called on each Update frame between OnStateEnter and OnStateExit callbacks
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        boss.LookAtPlayer();

        Vector2 target = new Vector2(player.position.x, rb.position.y);
        Vector2 newPos = Vector2.MoveTowards(rb.position, target, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        rb.MovePosition(newPos);

        if(Vector2.Distance(player.position, rb.position) <= attackRange)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
            animator.SetBool("AttackSwitch", switchAttack);
        }
    }

    // OnStateExit is called when a transition ends and the state machine finishes evaluating this state
    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        animator.ResetTrigger("Attack");
        switchAttack = !animator.GetBool("AttackSwitch");
    }

the switch works great, one attack is exuceted, goes back to run, starts next attack.
but now i have the problem that i dont really know how to cooldown, i want it to stop for a bit in Run but only if it attacked beforehand, no matter what solution i came up with it requieres WaitForSeconds but it does not exist in StateMachineBehaviour nor adding a MonoBehaviour object to the class works...
I tried adding a bool parameter to the animator, if the player is within attack range, the boss attacks and switches it to true, and in the OnStateEnter I check said parameter, if its true indicating that there was an attack before entering the state i start the coroutine(with the monobehaviour object), else attack immediately:
if (animator.GetBool("Enters"))
    {
        monoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(WaitCooldown(2));
    }
    else
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        rb = animator.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boss = animator.GetComponent<Boss>();
    }

    IEnumerator WaitCooldown(float sec)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        rb = animator.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boss = animator.GetComponent<Boss>();
    }

Im really new to the StateMachineBehavior so idk if theres something im missing, thank you all)
Brackeys tutorial
